# SPARQL How to get year as integer from xsd:date

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have a SPARQL query which choose people who has year of birth 1990. How could I get only year from xsd:date format? I can see how to get year from xsd:dateTime using year() but it doesn't work on xsd:date.

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?birthYear
WHERE
{dbr:Ilse_DeLange dbo:birthDate ?birth
 #how to get year only as a integer?}
```

Comment: One common problem is that data has messy (i.e. incorrect) dates, such as not datatype xsd:date or with a bad lexical form.  Both cause YEAR() to fail even if supported as an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the specs, `year()` works on `xsd:dateTime` literals only.

Depending on the triple store, you might try to convert to `xsd:dateTime` first:

```sql
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT (year(xsd:dateTime(?birthDate)) as ?birthYear) WHERE {
  dbr:Ilse_DeLange dbo:birthDate ?birthDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it without any assumptions on extensions for xsd:date needs a bit of string bashing.

You can use REPLACE on the lexical form of ?birthDate to get year as a string then cast it to xsd:integer.

`REPLACE(str(?birthDate), "(\\d*)-.*", "$1")`